# validacion de ganador en Javascript y html

Tags: javascript, html5

yo quiero que funcione la validacion para ver el ganador de un juego de gato pero no se porque no lo reconoce, coloque la funcion en la parte inferior con el nombre de validation y tambien tengo problemas en la parte donde creo los botones con el ciclo y no logro hacer que salgan en columnas de 3x3.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function cargar(){
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
var boton = document.createElement("input");
boton.type = "button";
boton.value = " ";
boton.id = "b"+i;
boton.classList.add("gato");
boton.setAttribute("onclick","check(this.id,this.disabled)","validation(this.id,this.disabled)");
document.body.appendChild(boton);
}
}
var a=0;
function check(valor){
if (a==0 ){
a = a + 1 ;
document.getElementById(valor).value = "O";
document.getElementById(valor).disabled = true;
validation();
}else{
a = a- 1;
document.getElementById(valor).value = "X";
document.getElementById(valor).disabled = true;
validation();
}
}
function validation(valor2){
 if((b1==b2 && b2==b3)||(b1==b5 && b5==b9)||(b3==b5 && b5==b7)||(b4==b5 && b5==b6)||(b7==b8 && b8==b9)||(b1==b4 && b4==b7)||(b2==b5 && b5==b8)||(b3==b6 && b6==b9)){
  alert(" ganaste");
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: No estás haciendo ningún tratamiento para mostrarlos de a tres. Podrías contar y cuando sea divisible por tres el conteo, cambias de línea. Sobre la función de validación, se entiende que quieres validar cada una de las opciones posibles de un juego de gato terminado, pero no es claro qué es b1, b1... esas variables no están definidas. Procura incluir en tu pregunta el error que salga en la consola de tu navegador al ejecutar ésto

Comment: hay que modificar varias cosas en el codigo para que funcione correctamente, como mencionas la validacion y construccion de la cuadricula, dame un momento para poder ayudarte

Comment: No me da error solo que no se si estoy aplicando bien la funcion y si se les da valor en la parte del ciclo de la funcion cargar solo que es automatico

Comment: vale muchisimas gracias

Comment: si tienes razon, esta bien ingenioso la forma como armaste el tablero y creates el evento, ya arregle el problema de la cuadricula, falta la validacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YA TENGO LA SOLUCION:**

Me tarde un tiempo en coseguirla porque queria hacer una regla mediante una rutina para evaluar los 3 caso (horizontal, vertical y diagonal), tambien hay que excluir el espacio como valor en la comparacion.

1) La regla permite saber cual es el ganador

2) marcar la linea ganadora

3) Separe el codigo de validacion de la carga de la grilla para mejor comprension

Tambien se arreglo la tabulacion para que mostrara los cuadros como una grilla de 3 x 3

**Aqui esta el codigo funcionando perfectamente:**

```html
 <script language="JavaScript">
        function cargar(){
            for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                var boton = document.createElement("input");
                boton.type = "button";
                boton.value = "   "; // mas espacio
                boton.id = "b"+i;
                boton.classList.add("gato");
                boton.setAttribute("onclick","check(this.id,this.disabled)","validation(this.id,this.disabled)");
                document.body.appendChild(boton);
                // salto de linea
                if (i%3==0) {
                   var saltoLinea=document.createElement("br");
                   document.body.appendChild(saltoLinea);
                }
            }
        }
    


        cargar();

        // eventos
        var a=0;
        function check(valor){
            if (a==0 ){
                a = a + 1 ;
                document.getElementById(valor).value = "O";
                document.getElementById(valor).disabled = true;
                validation();
            }else{
                a = a- 1;
                document.getElementById(valor).value = "X";
                document.getElementById(valor).disabled = true;
                validation();
            }
        }

        // validacion;
        /*
          b1|b2|b3
          b4|b5|b6
          b7|b8|b9  
        */
        function validation(valor2){
          var result ='';
          var linea = null;
          var a = new Array(10);
          for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
              a[i]= document.getElementById('b'+ i).value;
          }
          // console.log(a);

          // regla horizontal
          var btn=[{a:1,b:2,c:3},{a:4,b:5,c:6},{a:7,b:8,c:9}]; // patron de arreglo a comparar
          for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
             // console.log(a[btn[i].a] + '  ' + a[btn[i].b] + ' ' + a[btn[i].c] );
             // compara una triada
             if (a[btn[i].a]=='X' && a[btn[i].b]=='X' && a[btn[i].c]=='X') { result='X'; linea = btn[i]; break; }
             if (a[btn[i].a]=='O' && a[btn[i].b]=='O' && a[btn[i].c]=='O') { result='O'; linea = btn[i]; break; }
          }

         // regla vertical
         var btn=[{a:1,b:4,c:7},{a:2,b:5,c:8},{a:3,b:6,c:9}]; // patron de arreglo a comparar
          for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
            //  console.log(a[btn[i].a] + '  ' + a[btn[i].b] + ' ' + a[btn[i].c] );
             // compara una triada
             if (a[btn[i].a]=='X' && a[btn[i].b]=='X' && a[btn[i].c]=='X') { result='X'; linea = btn[i]; break; }
             if (a[btn[i].a]=='O' && a[btn[i].b]=='O' && a[btn[i].c]=='O') { result='O'; linea = btn[i]; break; }
          }   
               
         // regla diagonal
         var btn=[{a:1,b:5,c:9},{a:7,b:5,c:3}]; // patron de arreglo a comparar
          for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
             // console.log(a[btn[i].a] + '  ' + a[btn[i].b] + ' ' + a[btn[i].c] );
             // compara una triada
             if (a[btn[i].a]=='X' && a[btn[i].b]=='X' && a[btn[i].c]=='X') { result='X'; linea = btn[i]; break; }
             if (a[btn[i].a]=='O' && a[btn[i].b]=='O' && a[btn[i].c]=='O') { result='O'; linea = btn[i]; break; }
          }   


            // reportar el ganador
            if (result.length>0) {
                document.getElementById('b'+ linea.a).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                document.getElementById('b'+ linea.b).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                document.getElementById('b'+ linea.c).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                setTimeout(function() { alert('Gano el jugador: ' + result); },300);
            }
        }
        
</script>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias sin ti no abria podido

Comment: Siempre para ayudar

Comment: Comente las salidas de console.log() para mostrar mejor el resultado de la pantalla

Comment: si igual es lo que estoy viendo... de verdad gracias

Answer (score 0):

No veo en tu codigo que este agregando un valor a b1, b2, b3, bn... Considero que tendrias que inicializar b1,b2,b3,bn... con valor nulo y marcar cada cuadro con un valor del jugador. Mas o menos asi:

```
var b1 = null;
var b2 = null;
var b3 = null;
.
.
.
var bn = null;
var a = 0;

function check(valor){
    let asignacion = '';
    if (a==0 ){
        a++;
        document.getElementById(valor).value = "O";
        document.getElementById(valor).disabled = true;
    }else{
        a--;
        document.getElementById(valor).value = "X";
        document.getElementById(valor).disabled = true;
    }
    //asignando a la casilla el valor del jugador
    asignacion = valor+'= a';
    eval(asignacion);

    //ejecutando validacion
    validation();
}
```

Comment: vale gracias pero esque b1,b2,bn... esta siendo agregados en el ciclo y son las id de cada boton. es un poco curioso pero asi esta